# What is the difference between decorator syntax @Input('someValue') and @Input() in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, decorator

I have not been clear what the difference between the two types of syntax is, thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Input()` will not have any alias naming.

- Example

  ```
   @Input() student:any[];
   <component [student]="...">
  ```

`@Input('someValue')` will take alias as someValue

- Example

  ```
  @Input('studentInfo') student:any[];

  <component [studentInfo]="...">
  ```

Explanation when you use alias make sure that you are using the alias in the HTML template.

Comment: @JustinCastillo happy tp help you

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Aravind post this is also the case for `@Output` and `@ViewChild` directives.